Notifications not showing when app is in the background (ios, flutter_local_notifications)
I am using the flutter_local_notifications to show notifications. On iphone the notifications is not displayed when the app is in the background. But when I open the app again, the notifications get shown.
I have done all the following:
AppDelegate.swift
import Flutter
import UIKit
import flutter_local_notifications

@main
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {

    // This is required to make any communication available in the action isolate.
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { (registry) in
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
    }

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as 
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}

Then in my notifications service class:
Future<void> _setupIOSHeadsUp() async {
    await _firebaseMessaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      sound: true,
      badge: true,
    );
  }

Future<void> showBigTextNotification({
    required String title,
    required String body,
    String? payload,
  }) async {
    // Set up BigTextStyleInformation
    final bigTextStyleInformation = BigTextStyleInformation(
      body, // Big text content
      contentTitle: title, // Title for expanded view
    );
    final notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        notificationChannel.id,
        notificationChannel.name,
        channelDescription: notificationChannel.description,
        importance: notificationChannel.importance,
        priority: Priority.high,
        styleInformation: bigTextStyleInformation,
      ),
      iOS: const DarwinNotificationDetails(
        presentAlert: true,
        presentSound: true,
        presentBadge: true,
      ),
    );

    return _flutterLocalNotifications.show(
      Random().nextInt(100),
      title,
      body,
      notificationDetails,
      payload: payload,
    );
  }

Setting the following in my payload helped a bit. Now I can receive notifications when app is in background.
apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          "content-available": 1,
        },
      },
    },

When ios app is terminated, still no notification is received.

Are  you trying to use local_notification? Or you want use remote push notification?

I don't understand the question. I am using fluter_local_notifications package.

I mean, u trying to show notification remote from server?Or u trying to use notification when app is open?

I get notifications from firebase messaging and I use flutter_local_notifications to display to transform and display the notifications on user device.

ah now i understand,  do you use 'data' key , in your payload? Could you show payload?

I had to add apns to my payload for it to work properly.
But what I have noticed is that 1 time out of 5 the notifications won't be delivered when the app is closed/terminated. I think I can live with that as to my knowledge this happens quite often with ios which does not treat background notifications with high priority.
const message = {
    data: {
      "key1": value1,
      "key2": "value2",
    },
    token: fcmToken,
    apns: {
      headers: {
        "apns-priority": "10",
        "apns-push-type": "background",
      },
      payload: {
        aps: {
          "content-available": 1,
        },
      },
    },
  };

